# Properties Access

Tags: php, oop, reflection

Im trying to list all properties of a class (that extends from another one) excluding the parent's properties.

```
Class A{
    var $prop1;
    var $prop2;
}

Class B extends A{
    var $prop2;
    var $prop3;
}
```

I tried to do this

```
$refClass = new ReflectionClass($o);
var_dump($refClass->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC));
```

But I got all properties, including $prop1. Is there any way to list all properties excluding those that are defined in Class A?

Im want to get a list that has $prop2 and $prop3

Comment: You can use the property's [getDeclaringClass()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdeclaringclass.php) method to identify the class within the inheritance tree where the property is defined

Comment: Seems _getDeclaringClass()_ have some problems... It returns a unexpected results, sounds like a bug (there're opened tickets about it).
I didn't found a real solution yet, but I'm still looking for it or waiting for an expert here

Comment: I see that some version has different behaviours. http://3v4l.org/BN9gZ. What is your php version?

Comment: **Don't use `var $var;` in your objects**. This isn't PHP 4 any more. Use the correct access modifier. `protected $var;` will do.